# How to use the NASA "Distance to the Nearest Coast" dataset?

Tags: python, geospatial

How would I use the dataset at http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/DOCS/DistFromCoast/ to efficiently determine the distance of a given coordinate (lat,lng) to the nearest coastline?

It's quite a large file. Is there a library that can help with processing this kind of data?

Comment: I don't see why you need a library.  You need to do a bit of rounding (looking at the datafile, it has resolution down to `.04`) and then just linearly search for that point in the datafile.  If you need to find a lot of points you can consider reading the whole file into a `dict` in-memory, it should fit if you have more than a gig of RAM.

Comment: You could also use the Distance to Coast REST API at http://www.kbgeo.com instead.

Comment: At $1 per request, kbgeo is pretty ridiculously expensive for public data.